# Android get value after setting setText on onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an adapter class which has a onbindviewholder method which gets items from list items and set text values by position.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Task product = productList.get(position);
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getName());
    holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getTasks());
    holder.textViewRating.setText(String.valueOf(product.getTaskdetails()));
    holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getCurrentdate()));
    holder.textviewlocation.setText(String.valueOf(product.getTasklocation()));
}
```

I need to know how do I pass these setText string values using intent into to another activity?
How do I extract the setText values to another string variable?

Comment: Your first question you can read in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick . You can put your intent in there. Second, you already did it. The `String.valueOf(product.getTaskdetails())` is a string, then you can put it to string variable.

Comment: you want data TextView put the other activity with intent???